# How to get pixel in C without generating any trash

Tags: c++, c, performance, graphics, recycle-bin

I need to check four pixels at screen at least five times per second. Also, these pixels aren't on the application. If possible I would like a solution that doesn't use any external libraries (in another words, that uses graphics.h, windows.h or winusers.h). It's okay if the solution uses C++ libraries. I tried using GetPixel() but it generated a ridiculous amount of trash with the audiodg.exe. If you know a solution with SFML or other external libraries please answer here too.

Comment: "_it generated a ridiculous amount of trash with the audiodg.exe_" - Can you elaborate? I don't see how `GetPixel()` and `audiodg.exe` are connected. What does _trash_ mean?

Comment: When you use graphics.h functions it calls audiodg.exe, but I don't know how to get rid of the trash that it generates. For example to call GetPixel I need to call GetDC, that allocates memory to a handle(void*). There's the ReleaseDC, but i'm calling and it's not releasing the trash. I want help from someone that knows windows.h and knows how to use the DeleteObject, DeleteDC, ReleaseDC ... There's a surprisingly low content on how to use these functions! So, audiodg.exe is a program that is called when you use graphics.h functions and executes what is asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how `GetPixel()` can be used:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void disp_colorref(COLORREF c) {
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetRValue(c)) 
              << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetGValue(c))
              << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetBValue(c));
}

int main()
{
    HDC dt = GetDC(nullptr);          // get screen DC
    if (dt == nullptr) return 1;      // error getting DC

    COLORREF c = GetPixel(dt, 0, 0);  // get the pixel color at  0, 0
    if (c == CLR_INVALID) return 2;   // error getting pixel

    std::cout << std::hex;

    disp_colorref(c);                 // display the pixel's RGB value

    ReleaseDC(nullptr, dt);           // release the DC
}
```

---

The above will however leak a `DC` resource if `GetPixel` fails, so you could put the resource in a RAII wrapper which also removes the need to manually call `ReleaseDC` when you are done with it. Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// a RAII wrapper for a HDC
class dc_t {
public:
    dc_t(HDC DC) : 
        dc(DC) 
    {
        if (dc == nullptr) throw std::runtime_error("invalid DC");
    }
    dc_t(const dc_t&) = delete;
    dc_t(dc_t&& rhs) noexcept :
        dc(std::exchange(rhs.dc, nullptr))
    {}
    dc_t& operator=(const dc_t&) = delete;
    dc_t& operator=(dc_t&& rhs) noexcept {
        dc = std::exchange(rhs.dc, nullptr);
        return *this;
    }
    ~dc_t() {
        if(dc) ReleaseDC(nullptr, dc);
    }

    operator HDC () { return dc; }

private:
    HDC dc;
};

void disp_colorref(COLORREF c) {
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetRValue(c)) 
              << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetGValue(c))
              << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(GetBValue(c));
}

int main()
{
    dc_t dt = GetDC(nullptr);

    COLORREF c = GetPixel(dt, 0, 0);
    if (c == CLR_INVALID) return 2;

    std::cout << std::hex;

    disp_colorref(c);
}
```